# Pass a value to another page to open the PDF

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

I pass a PDF file link to this page, when I print it is always present, but the page once reads the PDF file and when go back and do that agian does not read the link, I don't know why?

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
class ReadPdf extends StatefulWidget {

  final String value;
  ReadPdf({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ReadPdfState createState() => _ReadPdfState();
}

class _ReadPdfState extends  State<ReadPdf>{
  PDFDocument document;
  var my_uid;
  loadFromUrl() async{
    document = await PDFDocument.fromURL('${widget.value}');
    print('yes' + widget.value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    loadFromUrl();

    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){

      setState(() {
        my_uid = user.uid;
        print(user.uid);
      });
    }).catchError((e){
      print(e);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: document !=null ? PDFViewer(
                  document: document,
                ) : Text('Try agian'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is "async" operation that is not completed yet when the build method was called.

Instead of contidional `document !=null`, try put the loadFromUrl into FutureBuilder, like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                future: loadFromUrl(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }

                  //or snapshot.data if your loadFromUrl returns the document, I think that is more "correct"
                  return PDFViewer(document: document);
                },
              )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and your method has to return a future of something (PDFDocument in your case)

```
Future<String> loadFromUrl() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  }
```